# PayPal payments with both PayPal Accounts and Credit Cards on iOS as a third-party merchant

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to add payments to an iOS App I'm developing, where some people sell physical goods, and other ones buy them, but I didn't find any solution that fits my needs.

Currently, I've added the [PayPal MPL SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/), as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/).

However, the MPL library seems to **not** provide Credit Card support, furthermore its graphic is so outdated on iOS7.

Other options I found are:

- **[PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)**, but it's based on the *REST API*, while I need to support third-party payments and eventually chained/parallel payments, and all these features are not available with the *REST API*.
- **[PayPal MEC](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mobile-express-checkout/) (Mobile Express Checkout)**, using it inside an `UIWebView`.

  Even if it does provide both Credit Card & PayPal Account as payment methods, I didn't find any way to support third-party payments (a.k.a. me/the app being the `API Caller` with another PayPal account being the `Receiver`).

  Furthermore, MEC [does not support parallel payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/#id3817a5d1-ab29-41d1-89bb-5d71370409d0), multiple receivers, etc., but for now this would not be a problem, If I only could use it with **third-party** payments.
- **PayPal Adaptive Payments API**, I even tried to use PayPal **AP API** without the SDK given by PayPal, obtaining the `payKey` server-side and loading `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-KEY` inside an `UIWebView` by myself.

  However this page hasn't a **mobile** version, so it's simply unusable.

  I've tried even using the *embedded webflow*, the one with `&extType=mini`, but it looks awful. Just not designed for this.

In conclusion my question is:

How can I support both **credit cards & paypal accounts** payment methods, on **mobile devices**  (iOS in this case), if I need to handle them as a **third-party merchant**?

Comment: Hey were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Currently we are using MEC and we are looking for a solution to support Third-party payments with it. It seems like there are some parameters we can use to achieve the desired result, but we are still investigating.

Comment: Hey have you found a solution? The MPL UX is terrible.

Comment: Hii @leonardfactory I also need chained payments with Credit Card support..Did you find any solution...

Comment: @leonardfactory is PayPal a must-use for you, or are you open to other solutions? I can suggest a great pathway forward here if you're open to other processing companies.

Comment: @RyanKreager PayPal is not a must, I'm open to other processing companies as well as PP. Even if I'm working on other projects now, I'm still interested and I'd like to listen to your ideas.

@ Vidhyanand currently I stopped this app development, so no, no solutions for now.

Comment: @leonardfactory if PayPal is not a must-have, I highly recommend Stripe. The are awesome for cc payments and simple to set up. Low fees and almost no technical uptake if you know iOS already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PayPal's website](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) regarding integration *third-party support, parallel, and chained payments* are not supported yet.

> **MPL libraries**
>
> PayPal is replacing the old Mobile Payments Libraries
>   (MPL) with the new PayPal Android and iOS SDKs. The new Mobile SDKs
>   use the PayPal REST API. The MPL uses the Adaptive Payments API (a
>   PayPal Classic API).
>
> The new SDKs **currently do not support third-party, parallel, and
>   chained payments**. To incorporate these features into your mobile apps
>   see the [MPL on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL) and [MPL documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/). Issues related to MPL
>   should be filed in the following repository: [sdk-packages](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/)
>
> For existing Express Checkout integrations, or additional features, we recommend [Mobile Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/).

**However**, one could accept/process credit cards with PayPal by using `PayPalConfiguration.acceptCreditCards` property.